# What would cause a "Precondition not met while deleting gs:xxx at generation 0" when recursively deleting a directory

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm facing some intermittent inconsistency issues with the implicit directories and implicit inferring

**Description of my Scenario:**

I write a Parquet file into a directory on the bucket and if that parquet ends up empty (Data read from API returned 0 rows) I recursively delete the directory.

During that I'm facing issues with

```
Precondition not met while deleting gs://bucket_name/1651198141345/000000/ at generation 0. Attempt 1. Retrying:
{"code":412,"errors":[{"domain":"global","location":"If-Match","locationType":"header","message":"At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold.","reason":"conditionNotMet"}],"message":"At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold."}
```

Since I'm using the HadoopFileSystem I make a check on the delete. If it's false I throw an exception and halt the process. Im trying to understand why I sometimes face this and sometimes don't.

I looked over the source quickly and I think it's failing because the generation id is 0. Generation is 0 if it was an inferred. directory sine I have (the default) infer directory enabled but why is it being inferred? if I was missing an explicit creation of an empty directory wouldn't it have been consistent?

Is the reason behind the failure of the deletion actually the 0 generation id? if so how and why is it happening on an intermittent basis?

I even tried manually debugging my code to see if it was always like this and when I try to debug it it's able to get the GoogleStorageStatusInfo correctly with a proper generation id and not create a shadow implicit directory

**Relevant Environment Configs:**

Hadoop Connectors: 1.9.17 (Due to an issue with transitive dependencies upgrading is hard but it's hard to get on the next 3 months)

fs.gs.implicit.dir.repair.enable -> false: Due to issues with listStatus returning deleted/not found directories. Disabling auto-repair seemed to fix the issue across many buckets

fs.gs.performance.cache.enable -> false (not set explicitly and working with the default)

Tips are appreciated even if they are a configuration changes or some insights into what is causing this. Thanks!

Comment: Setting if-generation-match:0 will cause the operation to fail if there is a current generation of the object. Why do you apply this condition while deleting the directory - that would cause the delete to run only if there is no current generation? Or are you saying you run code after the delete to check that it succeeded, by setting this condition?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I'm not setting it anywhere actually I'm using the https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors so I simply call fs.delete(file, true) and check it's returned value. If it's true then I mark it as a success if not then a failure.

The pre-condition not met is logged multiple times in my log file

Comment: I'm not even sure if the precondition fail is due to the 0 generation id it was just an assumption on my part. Please correct me if I'm wrong on it.

Comment: You may contact https://cloud.google.com/support-hub for best investigation/troubleshooting of your use case so they can also inspect your project.